# What's a quick way to align text?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indentation

I am often writing quick statements in which I would like the following lines to continue underneath the end of the first.

Is there a quick way to do this (requires arrays?)

```
this is the first sentence:
                           continue here
                           and here too
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the [`tabbing`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/anton/latex/ltx-58.html) environment.

```
\begin{tabbing}
this is the first sentence:\=\\
\>continue here\\
\>and here too\\
\end{tabbing}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\parskip 2em
\newcommand\parbrlap[2]{\brlap{\parbox[t]{#1}{#2}}}
\begin{document}


this is the first sentence\parbrlap{2in}{continue here\\and here}

this is the first sentence\brlap{continue just here}

\tllap{Top left}\bllap{Bottom left}A demonstration%
\tclap{Top center}\bclap{Bottom center} of lapping%
\trlap{Top right}\brlap{Bottom right}.

this is the first sentence\parbrlap{2in}{\tiny\lipsum[3]}
\end{document}
```

[image]